# jQuery shows "undefined" for values after unchecking checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to jQuery and AJAX and I was trying to set up a script that displays a MySQL table which can be updated. I included a checkbox to update various entries at the same time. It works fine but if I uncheck the checkbox, all values change to "undefined".

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

function fetch_data()
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"select.php",
        method:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data)
        {
            var html = '';

            for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
            {
                var bezahlstatus = data[count].bezahlstatus;
                var guest_amount = data[count].guest_amount;

                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+data[count].id+'" data-email="'+data[count].email+'" data-guest_amount="'+data[count].guest_amount+'" data-date_reservation="'+data[count].date_reservation+'" data-menu_own="'+data[count].menu_own+'" data-bezahlstatus="'+data[count].bezahlstatus+'" class="check_box"></td>';
                html += '<td>'+data[count].email+'</td>';
                html += (guest_amount == "") ? "<td>0</td>" : "<td>"+guest_amount+"</td>";
                html += '<td>'+data[count].date_reservation+'</td>';
                html += '<td>'+data[count].menu_own+'</td>';
                html += (bezahlstatus == null || bezahlstatus == "") ? "<td>nicht bezahlt</td>" : "<td>"+data[count].bezahlstatus+"</td>";

            }

            $('tbody').html(html);
        }
    });
}

fetch_data();


$(document).on('click', '.check_box', function() {
    var html = '';

var guest_amount = $(this).data('guest_amount');
var bezahlstatus = $(this).data('bezahlstatus');

if(this.checked)
{
    html = '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" data-email="'+$(this).attr('email')+'" data-guest_amount="'+$(this).attr('guest_amount')+'" data-date_reservation="'+$(this).attr('date_reservation')+'" data-menu_own="'+$(this).attr('menu_own')+'" data-bezahlstatus="'+$(this).attr('bezahlstatus')+'" class="check_box" checked></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="email[]" class="form-control" value="'+$(this).data("email")+'" /></td>';
    html += (guest_amount == "") ? '<td>0</td>' : '<td>'+guest_amount+'</td>';
    html += '<td>'+$(this).data('date_reservation')+'</td>';
    html += '<td><select name="menu_own[]" id="menu_own_'+$(this).attr('id')+'" class="form-control"><option value="Hauptmenü 1">Hauptmenü 1</option><option value="Hauptmenü 2">Hauptmenü 2</option><option value="Hauptmenü 3">Hauptmenü 3</option></select></td>';
    html += '<td><select name="bezahlstatus[]" id="bezahlstatus_'+$(this).attr('id')+'" class="form-control"><option value="">nicht bezahlt</option><option value="bezahlt">bezahlt</option></select></td><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id[]" value="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" />';
}

else
{
    html = '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" data-email="'+$(this).attr('email')+'" data-guest_amount="'+$(this).attr('guest_amount')+'" data-date_reservation="'+$(this).attr('date_reservation')+'" data-menu_own="'+$(this).attr('menu_own')+'" data-bezahlstatus="'+$(this).attr('bezahlstatus')+'" class="check_box"></td>';
    html += '<td>'+$(this).data('email')+'</td>';
    html += (guest_amount == "") ? '<td>0</td>' : '<td>'+guest_amount+'</td>';
    html += '<td>'+$(this).data('date_reservation')+'</td>';
    html += '<td>'+$(this).data('menu_own')+'</td>'; 
    html += (bezahlstatus == null || bezahlstatus == "") ? '<td>nicht bezahlt</td>' : 

'<td>'+bezahlstatus+'</td>'; 
    }

$(this).closest('tr').html(html);

$('#menu_own_'+$(this).attr('id')+'').val($(this).data('menu_own'));

$('#bezahlstatus_'+$(this).attr('id')+'').val($(this).data('bezahlstatus'));

});

$('#update_form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($('.check_box:checked').length > 0)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"update.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            success:function()
            {
                alert('Der Eintrag wurde erfolgreich aktualisiert.');
                fetch_data();
            }
        });
    }
});

});
```

I tried to find the mistake in the code section where the checkbox is checked but I am unable to find it. Could someone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That is how value on checkbox work. If it is checked it has the value, if it is not checked it has no value. You should be checking it's checked property, not the value. Value is whatever you set like 0 or 1, yes or no, true or false etc.

Comment: Isn't this what if(this.checked) is doing? What do I need to change in your opinion? @NawedKhan

Comment: $(this).prop('checked')